# Bootstrap has-error not applied to span

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pug

This is a working example from [validator](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputTwitter" class="control-label">Twitter</label>
    <div class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
        <input type="text" pattern="^([_A-z0-9]){3,}$" maxlength="20" class="form-control" id="inputTwitter" placeholder="1000hz" required>
    </div>
    <span class="help-block with-errors">Up to 20 letters, numbers and underscores</span>
 </div>
```

And this is my example, with a `span` using the same `class`

```
    .form-group
    #datepicker.input-daterange.input-group
        input#offlineStartDate.input-sm.form-control(type='text')
        span.input-group-addon a
        input#offlineEndDate.input-sm.form-control(type='text')
        span.input-group-btn
            button#refreshDates.btn.btn-default.btn-sm(type='button')
                i.fa.fa-refresh.fa-lg
```

After validation (just checking if there are dates in the inputs), I fire this.
(I've tried setting `.input-group` and also `.form-group`)

```
$('#offlineStartDate').closest('.input-group').addClass('has-error');       
$('#refreshDates').addClass('btn-danger');
$('#refreshDates').blur();
```

And the problem is there's no `background-color` and no `border-color` in the `span`.
Here's a [screenshoot](http://postimg.org/image/mrlzuem7d/) showing the `datepicker` with the `span's class` not being applied, and the properties of that `span` from chrome's console.

Any idea why this is happening?

**EDIT**. Things I've tried

. I've forced the main div to have the class `.form-group.has-error` but still..., the `span` is not being properly rendered.
. I've replaced my custom `bootstrap` with the stock one just in case..., same thing happened.

**EDIT 2**

Two more screenshots on the applied `css`.

[Screen 1](http://postimg.org/image/dhisf5o3x/)
[Screen 2](http://postimg.org/image/iemzyuy9f/)

The custom `bootstrap` I'm using just affects tables and fonts. I didn't changed that much.

Comment: Try replacing `.closest('.input-group')` with `.prev('.input-group')`.

Comment: No, still not working. I've edited the question to make it more visual.

Comment: If you want to select `.input-group` from `offlineStartDate`'s level, shouldn't you use $('#offlineStartDate'). **parent()** .addClass('has-error'); rather than closest() ?

Comment: @WaldoJeffers `closest` searches for the parent until it reaches to the closest element which has class `.input-group`

Comment: @RahilWazir : My bad, I re-read jQuery docs. You're right, in that case, it doesn't change anything.
However, I think it's more a CSS problem than a JavaScript one. I think that *even though* the CSS class is applied to the element, *another* CSS rule takes precedence over the one shown on your screenshot.
Could you make another one showing *all* css rules applied to the element ? If I'm right, you should take a look at [CSS weight rules](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) if you've never heard of that, otherwise, I beg your pardon, it's pretty late over here.

Comment: As stated in my last edit, I've forced `.form-group.has-error` and still, the `span`'s class is not being fully applied. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, as I just told you the problem is not whether or not the CSS class is applied. You have *another* css rule (in Bootstrap, or in your custom Bootstrap, or in another css file...) that *overwrites* the one shown on your screenshot. Just because your css rule is that last to be applied doesn't mean it's the one the browser will listen to.
Show us another screenshot showing *all* css rules applied to the element, and read the link I mentionned above. I'm 90% sure that's your problem.

Comment: @WaldoJeffers oh thanks, and sorry for the late reply, been out for the weekend. What you say makes sense, I linked two more screens. Hope it's that! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the screenshots you provided, the problem is that you have two CSS rules with different values for the `border` property.

Now that you have clearly identified the problem, it should be very easy to correct it. If you are not able to find a solution by yourself (I'll suggest you some in a minute), I **highly** suggest you take a couple hours to *properly* learn CSS.

Your problem has nothing to do with "Jade" or "twitter-boostrap" (I also suggest you change those tags on your post). It is a pure (and very simple) CSS issue.

So, if you read the post on CSS Tricks I suggested you, you probably came to the conclusion that both `.input-daterange .input-group-addon` and `.has-error .input-group-addon` try to define a different border-color to your element, and have the same value of 10.
Thus, the css rule that is loaded at last takes precedence.

So you could load `bootstrap-custom.css` after `datepicker3.css`, or add specifity to your rule in `bootstrap-custom.css` by changing `.has-error .input-group-addon` to `.has-error span.input-group-addon` or whatever, as long as you add specifity to the rule.

But again, learn CSS properly, or you will come to SO to ask 10 questions like this one a day.

Hope that solves your problem.